# Understanding 人ってオーラって言うじゃない

Tags: grammar, particle-と, particle-って

Can any one please tell me how should one understand “人ってオーラって言うじゃない” in the below sentence? What’s the role of って after 人, I know it’s a colloquial form of と, but it’s a quoting particle, used for quoting speech or thought, but here it’s placed after 人, instead of speech or thought

> ちょっとある言葉を考えたことがあって、人ってオーラって言うじゃない

Comment: Could you give some more context? Maybe a whole paragraph including this sentence. This sentence is perfectly grammatical but nonsense to me...

Comment: https://youtu.be/c2kqLzJ1T5M you can check this video, this sentence starts from 0:09

Comment: Sounds like 「ちょっとある言葉をね、考えたことがあって、人ってオーラと言うじゃない」to me.

Comment: @kandyman Yes, you are right, I think here をね is as same as を, he sort of paused there, and then continued

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to meaning と, the って particle is also commonly used to introduce a topic (essentially functioning as a very casual-sounding version of は). I think this usage originally comes from an abbreviation of とは, but it's used much more widely than とは itself would be. In the sentence you've provided, we have both uses in succession, so it could be rephrased as 人はオーラと言うじゃない.

It's a little tricky to nail down the exact intended meaning of this utterance without further context, but it sounds to me like the person is trying to start a conversation about the word "aura". I'd probably translate the whole thing along the lines of:

> ちょっとある言葉を考えたことがあって、人ってオーラって言うじゃない
>   I've been thinking a bit about a certain word lately - people talk about "aura", right?

I'm not entirely confident in this interpretation, because the use of を after ある言葉 seems a little odd for "thinking about" a word (something like について would sound more natural there to me), but this could simply be due to casual usage. Or I guess it could be that the ある言葉 is actually a new word that the speaker thought up themselves(?!), and the mention of オーラ is just leading into it? Maybe that's a bit of a stretch...

Comment: https://youtu.be/c2kqLzJ1T5M you can check this video for context, the sentence starts at 0:09

Comment: Yep, looks like my original interpretation was on the mark and the を isn't implying anything different from について.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between を考える and と考える.

When you use ～を考える you "think about" , i.e. using を to mark what you are thinking about as the direct object of your thought.　In that sense it is like について.

When you use と考える you "think that", or "consider that" i.e. the と is functioning like a quotative particle which indicates the exact thought you are having.

ペットの名前**を**考える to think **of** a name for a pet
環境問題**を**考える to think **about** environmental problems

ここは田舎だ**と**考える to think **that** this is a rural area